# Downloading Files from SFTP using jsch

Tags: java, jsch

I am using JSCH to download files from SFTP server.
I am using single session, with multiple channels to download files from different folders located in SFTP.
For this downloading process I have a set of scheduled jobs. Each job will:

1. open a new channel (`ChannelSftp`) everytime. channel name : sftp
2. uses method `ChannelSftp.ls()` to get the size of total number of files to download
3. If size(Vector) is greater than zero then uses `ChannelSftp.get(remotedir/'*.*', localdir)` to download all the files
4. finally closes the opened channel.

During the above process most of the times I am getting File Not Found or No Such File Exceptions and not downloading some files.

Can anyone please suggest me why it will happen. What may be the cause. How to resolve this problem

below is the code I am using:

```java
ChannelSftp channelSftp = null;

try {
    channelSftp = getChannelConnectionUtil().openChannel(); //SFTPConnection.getSession().openChannel("sftp");  

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    Vector numOfFiles = channelSftp.ls(ftpDir+"/*.*");

    if(numOfFiles.size() > 0){
        channelSftp.get(ftpDir+"/*.*",localDir); // Here I am getting error
    }
}  catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    getChannelConnectionUtil().disconnectChannel(channelSftp);
}
```

Comment: Please post the code that is giving you a problem.

Comment: Here you are getting *what* error? And where does it say that `ChannelSftp.get()` allows wildcards?

Answer (score 0):

Without your code it is hard to diagnose the issue.  I suggest forgetting the vector size check, simply iterate through your vector list and count the number of files grabbed. Here is the block of code I use to check for and download files from a remote host:

```
try {   
    ChannelSftp c = (ChannelSftp) channel;   
    c.lcd(localDir);
    logger.info("lcd " + c.lpwd());

    // Get a listing of the remote directory
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Vector<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> list = c.ls("."); 
    logger.info("ls .");

    // iterate through objects in list, identifying specific file names
    for (ChannelSftp.LsEntry oListItem : list) {
        // output each item from directory listing for logs
        logger.info(oListItem.toString()); 

        // If it is a file (not a directory)
        if (!oListItem.getAttrs().isDir()) {
            // Grab the remote file ([remote filename], [local path/filename to write file to])

            logger.info("get " + oListItem.getFilename());
            c.get(oListItem.getFilename(), oListItem.getFilename());  // while testing, disable this or all of your test files will be grabbed

            grabCount++; 

            // Delete remote file
            //c.rm(oListItem.getFilename());  // Deleting remote files is not requried in every situation.
        }
    }

    // Report files grabbed to log
    if (grabCount == 0) { 
        logger.info("Found no new files to grab.");
    } else {
        logger.info("Retrieved " + grabCount + " new files.");
    }                           
} catch(SftpException e) {
    logger.warning(e.toString());
} finally {
    // disconnect session.  If this is not done, the job will hang and leave log files locked
    session.disconnect();
    logger.info("Session Closed");
}
```

Comment: Hi Damien, In my SFTP when I touch the file it will be moved to another folder. Touch means either from program or tool like(WinScp). In the above code, while using get command. Please suggest If I am doing anything wrong.

Comment: the 'ls' should not cause the files to be touched.  This is likely a quirk of the mget in jsch.  Instead of doing an mget with a wildcard, try creating a list and iterating through it like I have done in my example.  For my solution, I was doing an FTP to a bank who has the same functionality you are describing... touched files are automatically archived.  My script works fine when grabbing from their server.

Comment: Hi Damien, thanks for you reply. I will try with your code, Can you please let me know what is the difference between fetching all files at once(as per my code) and fetching individual files(as per your code) ? And also I have to fetch files from SFTP server not from FTP.

Comment: Hi Damien, in the above code you are not setting the current directory.I mean you are setting only lcd but not cd. I have to set it right ?

Comment: Yes.  For my script, the SFTP host had a special login for us whose default directory is the location where the files are, so no directory change was necessary.  Changing remote directory works just like changing local directory, just use c.cd instead of c.lcd

Comment: Hi Damien, I am able to get the files, my scheduler will run jobs parallel to download files from different folders. For this all jobs will use the above method(c.get("*.*",mylocalfolder);). During this file contents are getting merged with the other files content in another folder. How this is happening even though I am just only reading the file content to update in my database? And is there anyway can we set the file attribute read-only? Please suggest me regarding this.